# Error code: 1069 MySql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

**Hola**

Estoy creando algunas tablas con llaves compuestas pero me sale el error 1069 que dice "Too many keys specified; max 1 keys allowed"

He intentado averiguar cuál es el problema pero no he encontrado nada y simplemente necesito configurar dos Campos para la llave primaria.

Comment: Sólo puede haber una llave (es lo que dice el mensaje de error), una llave compuesta no se define en cada columna sino con la sintaxis: `PRIMARY KEY(columna1,columna2)`.

Answer (score 0):

también tuve el mismo problema. La verdad no entendí porque pasaba ni como funciona pero lo solucione borrando la tabla y creandola nuevamente, mientras guardava por cada nueva columna y foreing key creada.